# How to add Sanitizers on C++ VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to add these santizers to VS Code.

g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG

I'm using ubuntu. Help me how to do it.

Comment: You forgot your input file ...

Comment: I use the same to build in geany it works!!

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I even get to know at which line there is some curious happenning using gdb